# Why does Ramda's R.adjust gives error in browser?

Tags: ramda.js

A simple call of R.adjust(). Works in Ramda JS playground.

```js
console.log(R.adjust(1, _ => 'X', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

But, gives error in browser - firefox and chrome:

```
TypeError: t is not a function       ramda.min.js:1:12792
```

Comment: It seems to be a problem with version 0.25, 0.26 and 0.27 work as expected.

Comment: @OriDrori - Thanks. Indeed the case. Assuming that this is a pure function, it should have had same behaviour in R's playground as well as browser. Is is that underlying node vs browser js which created issues in 0.25?

Comment: (Ramda author here): I don't know what caused that issue in 0.25.0.  As that is now back several versions, I'm not inclined to spend a lot of time on it, as we're not likely to fix it in any case.  I'm curious that we hadn't run across it before though.